# using external JS libraries in my angular 2 project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I need to use [this JS library](http://praytimes.org/code/v2/js/PrayTimes.js) in my angular 2 project

this question may be duplicate with me , but no answer worked for me

I tried to include the library as script tag in my index.html page

> It always does not see it http://localhost:8100/PrayTimes.js file is
>   not exist

also I wrote this code above

```
declare var PrayTimes:any;
```

I tried to use it in my constructor , but I am getting this error

> PrayTimes is not defined

Comment: Did you place the javascript file in `src/assets`? And included it as `<script src="assets/PrayTimes.js"></script>`?

Comment: Worked well , thank you (Y)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Place all javascript, external css, images etc. in `src/assets`

(will be compiled to `build/assets`)

In your `index.html`: `<script src="assets/yourJavascript.js"></script>`

Then you can just use it like you describe. (`declare var PrayTimes: any;`)

Comment: not wroking ionic, rc4, ERROR ReferenceError: testvar is not defined

Answer (score 58):

If you use angular-cli, you can add all your external JS files in assets folder. And then in `angular-cli.json` add them:

```
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        "../node_modules/moment/moment.js",
        "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js",
        "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js",
        "../node_modules/ng2-datetime/src/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js",
        "./assets/js/slimscroll.min.js",
        "./assets/js/inspinia.js",
        "./assets/js/metisMenu.js",
        "./assets/js/footable.all.min.js"
      ]
```

You can do it also with external styles:

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/ng2-toastr/bundles/ng2-toastr.min.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
        "../node_modules/ng2-datetime/src/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css",
        "./assets/scss/plugins/footable/footable.core.css",
        "./assets/scss/style.scss"
      ]
```

And of course you are right, then you need to add in `typings.d.ts`:

```
declare var PrayTimes:any;
declare var System: any;
declare var $: any;
declare var moment: any;
declare var Chart: any;
```

Comment: why no need for typings?

Comment: Just in case anyone else is wondering, you have to restart the angular server when adding dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use a function inside of an external library, so rather than declaring the JS class, I declared the JS function.

`declare function zoom(t: any);`