# Add paper package to Angular 2 application (VS 2015 update 3 project)

Tags: javascript, angular, canvas, visual-studio-2015, paperjs

I'm using asp.net MVC with Angular 2. (VS 2015 update 3).
I want to use paper.js to draw something on canvas selector.

What I did:

- install paper via npm and include it to project (in systemjs.config.js):

  ```
  var map = {
  'app': 'angular-app', // 'dist',
  ...
  'paper/paper-full': 'npm:paper/dist/paper-full.min.js',
  ...
  };
  ```
- import this js file to component with canvas:

  ```
  import { Component } from '@angular/core';
  import 'paper/paper-full';
  import 'angular-app/app/paper-canvas/paper-functions';

  @Component({
     selector: 'paper-canvas',
     templateUrl: 'angular-app/app/paper-canvas/paper-canvas.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['angular-app/app/paper-canvas/paper-canvas.component.css']
     })
  export class PaperCanvasComponent {
  title = 'canvas here'
  }
  ```
- my `angular-app/app/paper-canvas/paper-canvas.component.html`:

  ```
  <div class="well">
       <h2>{{title}}</h2>
       <canvas id="canvasArea">loading canvas</canvas>
  </div>
  ```
- and add functionality to draw on canvas:

  ```
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
         alert('it works');
   });

   window.onload = function () {
        alert("in func");
        // Get a reference to the canvas object
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasArea');
        // Create an empty project and a view for the canvas:
        paper.setup(canvas);
        // Create a Paper.js Path to draw a line into it:
        var path = new paper.Path();
        // Give the stroke a color
        path.strokeColor = 'black';
        var start = new paper.Point(100, 100);
        // Move to start and draw a line from there
        path.moveTo(start);
        // Note that the plus operator on Point objects does not work
        // in JavaScript. Instead, we need to call the add() function:
        path.lineTo(start.add([200, -50]));
        // Draw the view now:
        paper.view.draw();
  }
  ```

  All files loaded:
  [image: see this image]

As you can see I have loaded paper-full.js file and my file with draw function, but there no even alert I have.. 
I tried to write my draw-function into `angular-app/app/paper-canvas/paper-canvas.component.html` like `paperscript` but it wasn't work too.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to include paper.js so that it is available in whole application, since it is not written specially for angular I suggest you to look at this question
[using external JS libraries in my angular 2 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41120754/using-external-js-libraries-in-my-angular-2-project)

Everything else you did seems okay.