# Using money.js (external js lib) in angular4

Tags: angular

I'm trying to import js library `money.js` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/money) into an **angular 4** component.

I've installed it by `npm install money` and added the following code to my component:

```
declare var fx: any;

import '../../../node_modules/money/money.js';
```

Within the component i've tried to use it:

```
fx.convert(12.99, {from: "GBP", to: "HKD"});
```

Unfortunately, i'm getting an error that `fx` is not defined.

It's important to mention that `money.js` file **DID** get loaded (I find it when searching the sources in developer tools).

Can someone assist ?

Comment: Might be duplicate please see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/41121361/4712391

Comment: i've tried this way either.. doesn't work. as I mentioned: js file DID gets loaded. For some reason I cannot use the function fx within money.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access imported variable you should give it a name.

```
import * as fx from 'money';
```

should be enough. We're using `lodash` in our codebase like that.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can import your library like this :

```
import {* as fx} from  '../../../node_modules/money/money.js';
```