# undefined error while calling a javascript function in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

Can anyone help me how to call a function from external js file inside my angular2 component. Below is my code snippet, when I am trying to load the application it is throwing **App** is undefined error.

Here is my component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    templateUrl: './test.html'
})

export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {

    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        App.handleInit();
    }
}
```

here is my script inside app.js:

```
var App = function() {
    var handleInit = function() {
        console.log("Hello world");
    };
}();
```

When we are calling a function inside ngAfterViewInit it is throwing App is undefined error.

We are importing app.js file inside vendor.ts and we are using webpack.
Here app.js is loading fine but function was not working.

Please help us with a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is no angularjs 2, is just angular

Comment: We mean it is Angular2

Comment: create an interface for you js file and load that in you app module and access that method inside your angular 2 component

Comment: Can you please provide an example for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can access like that. does this help

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';
import '../../../../js/app.js'; //just example set this based on your path
declare var App: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    templateUrl: './test.html'
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.handleInit();
    }

    hadeleInit() {
        new app.handleInit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Shailesh Ladumor,
Thanks for your quick response, but here the problem is there is no export member in our app.js file(like App), so we are unable to import like what you suggested. Is there any other approach?

Comment: where you add this js file?

Comment: i have updated my answer. you need to import app.js file

Comment: Still we are getting App is not defined error like below.
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: App is not defined

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41120754/using-external-js-libraries-in-my-angular-2-project

Comment: When we tried to load the app.js file inside index.html everything working fine. But We don't want to load in it.

Comment: It is working fine only when I am loading js files inside index only why?

Answer (score 0):

You have to just simply **define App variable** in your component as below.

```
declare var App: any;
@Component({
   .....
})
```

And now your below call will work.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    App.handleInit();
}
```

Comment: Hi Sandip, Thanks for your response, We tried the above but still getting App is undefined error.

Comment: Is your JS is available in DOM? because I have tried this type of code in several component and it works for me

Comment: Yes the file is loading but function is not calling. We are loading the js files in vendor.ts but not in index.html file.

Comment: It seems when you call your function JS file and within function is not reachable, you have to import OR link that JS to global OR in required comonent

Comment: Is there any way to define java script variables globally?

Comment: Globally means define in your main landing page, if your page refresh and landing page change then you have to define in your current component

Comment: When we tried to load the app.js file inside index.html everything working fine. But We don't want to load in it.

Comment: You can load that javascript in your comoponent as well look at here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44276683/6606630

Comment: Is it better way to load external js files inside index.html in an angular2 application with webpack?