# unable to put external js file in angular2

Tags: html, typescript, angular2-routing

Hi I have started working on angular2. I came across a scenario where I have to put external javascript file in my angular2 application. I have tried as below.
At first I created **testjs.js** file and I added the below code

```
function test() {
    alert('TestingFunction')
}
```

Then in **index.html** I referenced as below.

```
 <script src="~/ClientApp/Assets/testjs.js"></script>
```

Then I have **fetchdata.component.js** file. I added below code into it.

```
declare var test: any;
 f() {
        new test();
    }
```

Finally in **fetchdata.component.html** I added below code.

```
<h1>
    <button (click)='f()'>Test</button>
</h1>
```

When click the button it prompts below error in browser.

```
FetchDataComponent.html:26 ERROR ReferenceError: test is not defined
    at FetchDataComponent.f (fetchdata.component.ts:15)
```

Can someone help me in this issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Check the accepted answer here out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41120754/using-external-js-libraries-in-my-angular-2-project. You are gonna have to place it in `src/assets` folder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I dont have src folder! should i need to create one? I selected angular template in vs2017.

Comment: are you using the angular-cli? if the project was created using the cli it would usually be there.

Comment: I am using angular template from vs 2017 core!