# Use or Import external javascript file in ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I am using ionic 2 and typescript angular 2
i have a problem that is i want to use external javascript file which is located into from https://xxxxxxxx.in/globaljsfile/sample.js
how can i use or import this

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41120754/using-external-js-libraries-in-my-angular-2-project.

Answer (score 0):

In your `index.html` just import your script like this at the end of the head:

```
...
<script src=" https://xxxxxxxx.in/globaljsfile/sample.js"></script>
</head>
```