# Angular - How to reference syntax in another script

Tags: angular

In my assets folder, I have a script called 'imageTools.js'. In one of my angular type script files I want to call 'imageTools' but it's unrecognised. What's the best way to do this?

As expected here's the error:

> [ts] Cannot find name 'ImageTools'.

Here's my code.

```
detectFiles(event) {
 this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;
  ImageTools.resize(this.selectedFiles[0], {
    width: 1000, 
    height: 1000 
  }, function (blob, didItResize) {
    this.testingBaseSixtyFour(blob);
  });    
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using external JS libraries in my angular 2 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41120754/using-external-js-libraries-in-my-angular-2-project)

Comment: You're right. Please close. Thanks @AymanElTemsahi

Answer (score 0):

import your jquery and javascript file in index.html. In your javascript file expose a variable through which you can call your functions.

Initialize that variable in your component and use it in your component it will work for you.

```
 var detect =  function(){
    detectFiles =function detectFiles(event) {
     this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;
      ImageTools.resize(this.selectedFiles[0], {
        width: 1000, 
        height: 1000 
      }, function (blob, didItResize) {
        this.testingBaseSixtyFour(blob);
      });    
    }
     return detectFiles :detectFiles 
    }
```

Initiallize **detect** this variable in your component with return type is **any**

//   detect. detectFiles (event)

like this